# Why do I get this message when I try to save in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I occasionally get this error message when trying to save in Excel:

[image]

Microsoft support (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2597034) explains that this error can occur when dealing with images; however, my workbook has no images nor has it ever had any images in it. It also references no external workbooks. My workbook just consists of a few worksheets of data.

Has anyone had this same error and been able to pinpoint the cause of it?

I am using Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

The file may have become corrupt. There are several approaches you could take:

1. Use Save As and save with a different file name. In the dialog above click "Continue". Now you have the old and the new version of the file. See if the new one still has all the stuff you need.
2. Cycle through html and back: Save the file as html. Then close the file, re-open and save as Excel again. Use a different name so you don't overwrite the original file. Check if it still has all the stuff you need.